# Carry forward new rank order from Pick Group Rank selected choices to Slider

Tags: javascript, slider, survey, qualtrics

I am working on Pick, Group and Rank question type wherein I want to carry forward the selected drag and drop choices in the new rank order as answer options to the following slider bar question.

I managed to use Qualtric's "Carry Forward" feature to display only the selected choices, but it retains the old order, not the new rank order.

In this 
[working example](https://berkeley.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_1FfEuEVI1Jt9bdX?Q_SurveyVersionID=current&Q_CHL=preview), if you drag options "b", "a", and "d" to the PGR group box, the slider options will only display "a", "b", and "d", but in that order. How can I get the slider options to display the selected choices in the new order?

I am trying the following approach but get stuck at step 2.

1. Multi-answer checkboxes -> carry forward selected choices using Qualtrics' function to
2. Rank order -> carry forward to
3. Sliders, where I use JavaScript to replace the slider labels with an array of sorted selected choices (according to the new rank order assigned in 2).

Step 3 works with an array that I declared in the JavaScript code.

```
   var choicesObject = this.getQuestionInfo().Choices;
   //choices is the array of choiceids
   var choices = Object.keys(choicesObject);
   var Qno = choices.length;
   var test = ['this', 'is', 'rad'];

   for (var x = 0; x < Qno; x++) {
     var id = choices[x];
     //var y = id + 1;
     var qid = "QID12-" + id + "-label";
     document.getElementById(qid).innerHTML = test[x];
   }
// This works
```

However, I have not figured out how to save the new rank order, and description in the environment as an array, or even as embedded data. I've tried saving it in an 2D array, sorting by rank and then saving it into embedded data fields as instructed [here](http://kurtmunz.com/2015/05/28/rank-order-carry-forward-in-qualtrics-with-javascript/).

This is my code in a blank page after the Rank question:

```
   // hide next button
      $('NextButton') && $('NextButton').hide();

      // store rank in first column, description in second column of array "choice"

      // le was saved as embedded data from Rank question to inform the current code how many choices to loop through

      var le = '${e://Field/gp1length}';
      var len = parseInt(le);

      var choiceArray = [];

      // create blank 2D array containing descriptions and rank orders
      for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        choiceArray[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
          choiceArray[x][y] = 0;
        }
      }

      // this does not work, the array contains NaNs
      for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        var y = x + 1;
        var rank = "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x" + y + "}";
        var desc = "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x" + y + "}";
        choiceArray[x][0] = parseInt(rank);
        choiceArray[x][1] = desc;
      }

      // attempt to sort array by rank order column
      choiceArray = choiceArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
      });

      for (var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        var y = x + 1;
        var name = "gp1r" + y;
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData(name, choiceArray[x][1]);
      }

      // advance to next screen
      this.clickNextButton();
```

But retrieving `choiceValues` by concatenating `choice-ids` with a `+` does not work in Qualtrics. More ever, as I am using the carry forward function, the `choice-ids` are remnants from the first multiple choice question, so a for loop strategy is not working as they do not go in sequential order (i.e. not 1, 2, 3, 4...).

I would greatly appreciate any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pipe the rankings into the slider question's JavaScript and rearrange the sliders' slider containers based on the rankings.

**Update based on updated question:**

You don't need an intermediate page or embedded variables.  Not having them will keep your response data clean. You can pipe the ranks into an array, remove the NaNs, sort, and reorder the sliders. jQuery makes this easier. Just one script on your slider question:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var ranks = [
        {"choice":"xx1", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x1}")},
        {"choice":"xx2", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x2}")},
        {"choice":"xx3", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x3}")},
        {"choice":"xx4", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x4}")},
        {"choice":"xx5", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x5}")},
        {"choice":"xx6", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x6}")},
        {"choice":"xx7", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x7}")},
        {"choice":"xx8", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x8}")},
        {"choice":"xx9", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x9}")},
        {"choice":"xx10", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x10}")},
        {"choice":"xx11", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x11}")},
        {"choice":"xx12", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x12}")},
        {"choice":"xx13", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x13}")},
        {"choice":"xx14", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x14}")},
        {"choice":"xx15", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x15}")},
        {"choice":"xx16", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x16}")},
        {"choice":"xx17", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x17}")},
        {"choice":"xx18", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x18}")},
        {"choice":"xx19", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x19}")},
        {"choice":"xx20", "rank": parseInt("${q://QID68/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x20}")}
    ];
    var tbody = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" div.ChoiceStructure > table.sliderGrid > tbody");
    var cleanRanks = [];
    jQuery.each(ranks, function(index) { if(!isNaN(this["rank"])) cleanRanks.push(this); });    //remove NaNs
    cleanRanks.sort(function(a,b) { return a.rank - b.rank; }); //sort by rank
    jQuery.each(cleanRanks, function() {
        tbody.append(tbody.find("tr[choiceid="+this["choice"]+"]"));    //order sliders
    });
});
```

Working example [survey](https://marketinview.ca1.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_eleKxrHt6xtxaAJ?Q_SurveyVersionID=current&Q_CHL=preview).

**Update 2:**

I've updated the code above to change the removal of NaNs from the array. Also, extended number of choices to 20.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I've attempted to implement it but ran into a few hiccups. I've updated the question with more details, and actual code.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @T.Gibbons , I tried to implement your answer as it is shorter and more elegant, but I could not populate the `ranks` array properly. I made sure to change the `QIDXX` and tried changing it to a 2D array but it still does not work. I used an `alert()` call to check on the `ranks` object and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjj8lhrk4lggvbo/Screen%20Shot%202018-08-10%20at%2011.32.16%20AM.png?dl=0) is what shows up.

Comment: The pipes change a bit based on if you have a PGR or a Rank question.  Your example survey had a Rank question, so that is how I set up my example.  If you have a PGR you need to adjust them.  Use console.log to check values for debugging (e.g. `console.log('ranks', ranks)`) and view them in your browser's (I recommend Chrome) developer tools console.

Comment: I added a link to a working example in the answer above.

Comment: I cannot get your solution to work for my actual survey of 20 Q. In [this example](https://berkeley.qualtrics.com/jfe/preview/SV_1FfEuEVI1Jt9bdX?Q_SurveyVersionID=current&Q_CHL=preview), selecting 1, 2, 3, 4 and then moving 2 up (so that the order is 2, 1, 3, 4) results in an order of 1, 3, 2, 4 in the slider page.

Comment: I couldn't recreate your issue, but when I extended the code I noticed that rank still had some NaNs after they should have been removed. So, I changed how they are removed in the code above. If you still have a problem, I can think of 3 reasons from most likely to least likely: (1) typo(s) in the ranks array (2) non-matching choiceids (Qualtrics could have renumbered them - for example they could be from 6 to 25 instead of 1 to 20 - you can check them through Qualtrics or with you browser's inspect feature. (3) the slider question is randomized.

Comment: It finally works with the new method to filter out NaNs. The choiceids remained in sequential order from 1-20. Your solution is more comprehensive because I also have html tags in the choices in my actual survey, and my replace-labels method does not replaces the entire html <span> container, only the first one, causing my tooltip .css script to fail subsequently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out with no intermediate page, and no embedded data as what T.Gibbons suggested. The approach is very similar to his suggestion, but with no jQuery, and uglier code, as I am very new to JavaScript. I just need to add the following script to the slider question's JavaScript box:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
   var choicesObject = this.getQuestionInfo().Choices;
   //choices is the array of choiceids
   var choices = Object.keys(choicesObject);

   rankArray = [
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x1}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x2}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x3}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x4}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceNumericEntryValue/x5}"
   ];

var rankArray = rankArray.filter(function(n) {
 return n != ''
   });

descArray = [
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x1}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x2}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x3}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x4}",
     "${q://QID11/ChoiceDescription/x5}"
  ];

   var descArray = descArray.filter(function(n) {
     return n != ''
   });

   var all = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < descArray.length; i++) {
     all.push({
       'rankArray': rankArray[i],
       'descArray': descArray[i]
     });
   }

   all.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.rankArray - b.rankArray;
   });

   rankArray = [];
   descArray = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
     rankArray.push(all[i].rankArray);
     descArray.push(all[i].descArray);
   }

   for (var x = 0; x < descArray.length; x++) {
     var id = choices[x];
     var qid = "QID12-" + id + "-label";
     document.getElementById(qid).innerHTML = descArray[x];
   }
});
```

Comment: The big difference is that you are changing the label text rather than moving the sliders, which is going to make the resulting data very confusing.  For example, in your slider response data your label will say it is 5 but it is really 3, and you'll have to reference the rank question to figure out which one it really is and it will be different for each respondent.

Comment: I agree. I exported the data and I would have to code up a unique crosswalk for each respondent to properly match up the final slider values to the correct choices. That is prone to problems. I will try your method again and update. Thanks again! You have been really helpful.